# Can't start Zune software

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface, zune-software

I can't get the Zune software to start. At all.
A fresh Windows 8 machine (Surface Pro 1, in case it matters) and I've just downloaded the Zune software from Zune.Net, so a brand new installer.

Installation is fine and when I open the application -

First it notifies me about the fact that the features of Zune have changed since the last time I ran it (which would be on another device) and asks me to restart Zune

I click OK and the screen goes completely blank.
I leave it for a while an Zune will ask if the UI is displayed correctly. I click no and am told the Zune software needs to be restarted and closes.

I start it again and see a message warning me that the video hardware is fully compatible with Zune and that it will keep me from enjoying video enhancements. Fine. I click 'Continue'.

But again I get a mostly black screen (some Gray 'stains' on the background this time) and nothing else.

I have ran Zune successfully on a Surface Pro before, but on another device)

Comment: The advice on this page got my Zune software working. [http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-other-devices/windows-phone-7/remove-and-reinstall-zune](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-other-devices/windows-phone-7/remove-and-reinstall-zune)

Comment: Magnus - this seem to have done the trick although I did get the black screen initially, this time, after a couple of minutes, Zune did proceed to start and I was able to connect the phone. if you put your answer as an answer I can accept it as such :-)